# Merge Rows and Sum Single Value in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I want to merge rows with mostly similar data but sum their quantity values, using the unique "id" value while keeping the rest of the data in the row intact.

The raw output looks like this:
[Original Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vw9xI.png)

| name | id | quantity | price | cost | label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1111 | 10 | 10 | 1 | label 1 |
| a | 1112 | 11 | 20 | 2 | label 2 |
| a | 1113 | 12 | 30 | 3 | label 3 |
| a | 1114 | 13 | 40 | 4 | label 4 |
| b | 2221 | 20 | 210 | 90 | label 21 |
| b | 2222 | 21 | 220 | 91 | label 22 |
| b | 2223 | 22 | 230 | 92 | label 23 |
| b | 2224 | 23 | 240 | 93 | label 24 |
| c | 1111 | 31 | 10 | 1 | label 1 |
| c | 1115 | 32 | 50 | 5 | label 5 |
| c | 1116 | 33 | 60 | 6 | label 6 |
| c | 1114 | 34 | 40 | 4 | label 4 |
| d | 1112 | 41 | 20 | 2 | label 2 |
| d | 1117 | 42 | 70 | 7 | label 7 |
| d | 1115 | 43 | 50 | 5 | label 5 |
| d | 1113 | 44 | 30 | 3 | label 3 |

And I want to transform it into this: [Transformed Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGgWZ.png)

| name | id | quantity | price | cost | label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| b | 2221 | 20 | 210 | 90 | label 21 |
| b | 2222 | 21 | 220 | 91 | label 22 |
| b | 2223 | 22 | 230 | 92 | label 23 |
| b | 2224 | 23 | 240 | 93 | label 24 |
| e | 1111 | 41 | 10 | 1 | label 1 |
| e | 1112 | 52 | 20 | 2 | label 2 |
| e | 1113 | 56 | 30 | 3 | label 3 |
| e | 1114 | 47 | 40 | 4 | label 4 |
| e | 1115 | 75 | 50 | 5 | label 5 |
| e | 1116 | 33 | 60 | 6 | label 6 |
| e | 1117 | 42 | 70 | 7 | label 7 |

Where `e` represents the group of `a`, `c`, and `d`, sums their quantity while the rest of the duplicate data is left as is.

This almost worked using the Consolidation and VLOOKUP functions, but VLOOKUP wouldn't return the whole row.

Comment: seems like a pivot table would work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Power Query for this.

Create a blank query using Data>Get Data>From Other Sources>Blank Query

On the Power Query Editor ribbon, use Home>Advanced editor

Replace the code that's already there with this code:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    AggCols = {"quantity","name"},
    GroupCols = List.RemoveItems(Table.ColumnNames(Source),AggCols),
    Groups = Table.Group(
                Source,
                GroupCols,
                {
                    {"quantity", each List.Sum([quantity])},
                    {"names",each Text.Combine([name]," + ")},
                    {"name", each if List.IsEmpty(List.Intersect({[name],{"a","c","d"}})) then "b" else "e"}
                }
            ),
    ReorderColumns = Table.ReorderColumns(Groups,{"name","id","quantity","price","cost","label","names"}),
    Sorted = Table.Sort(ReorderColumns,{{"name",Order.Ascending},{"id",Order.Ascending}})
in
    Sorted
```

Press Done to close the Advanced Editor:

[image]

If you want to remove the extra "names" column I added to the right of your table, just delete it in the Power Query Editor by selecting the header, right-click, remove.

When you're ready, use Home>Close & Load on the Power Query Editor ribbon.

Comment: This works pretty well; however, I discovered that `b` shares some `id` values with the other rows. Despite intersecting only three parameters, the fourth `name` value is included in the final table. E.g. `a+b+c` or `a+b+d`. I tried nesting the `List.Skip` function, but that didn't work/my syntax is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Power Query is the way to go.

Combine that with your output data not showing anything except returning single rows that are not actually combined with anything and I shan't show any cell formula solution since it probably wouldn't be what you want anyway, except by luck.

However, `VLOOKUP` will most certainly give you a return of more than just one cell. For instance, say the ID's you have are in column B and you want to return columns C, D, E, and F for a lookup done on the ID's. (So, ID column and those four columns are in the second parameter, the table of data for Excel to look in.)

You would use the function in this manner:

```
=VLOOKUP(K1, C1:F500, {2,3,4,5}, FALSE)
```

The `{2,3,4,5}` is an "array constant" and so Excel (all versions back to the first/only Windows 95 version... this is not part of the change in the way Excel handles arrays) will return the value from each of those four columns (so the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, and 5th columns in the data table it was told to look in (C1:F500) which are columns C, D, E, and F).

You can even reorder them in the output, so, say, `{4,5,3,2}` to return the columns in the order of E, F, D, then C.

You can also use an array constant in the first parameter. A common way would be a range, say K1:K4 to lookup four values, as it creates an array constant when Excel parses the formula. Putting the same value in each cell will still see the lookup returning values only from the first row it finds for the lookup value though, not something like the first four occurrences. But you can directly type the array constant, refer to a cell containing one, and so on, to get it into the function.

What you cannot do though is have more than one array constant in the function (haven't studied this, but it looks like "ANY function" not just this particular one) and have Excel use both. It will either use the first one it encounters and the first entry in the second/third/etc. ones it finds in the function's arguments, or simply immediately error. So `VLOOKUP({"horse","cow","pig",A1:F500,{2,3,4},FALSE)` will return three COLUMNS of output, one each for horse/cow/pig, but only one column's cell value from each's row's columns B, C, and D. (To get three ROWS of output, you'd use a semi-colon separator instead of the comma above (`;` vs. `,` separating those animal names).)

But `VLOOKUP` can absolutely, positively, provide as many columns of return data as you wish. (Actually, you can even have repeats of the same column:  {2,3,2,2,2,4} would give you six cells of output with column 2 from the lookup table appearing four times.)

The refusal to use a second (or more) such array constant happens in quite a few other functions and is probably the actual mechanics behind very few functions returning several row/several column results. `XLOOKUP` for instance. A column of results 100,000 cells deep, sure. A row of results 12,000 columns wide, sure. A 2x2 block... no.

**But if you have a solution in hand that ONLY needed `VLOOKUP` to return all the columns you wanted rather than one, this one little change will make it work for you.**

But if you know Power Query, or feel up to trying it, it surely is the way you'd like to go.